# Passing parameters to the ViewModel using a custom INavigationService Implementation?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, dependency-injection, mvvm-light

I've built a small app using MVVM Light, and I've reached a point in which I need to pass parameters between a few different ViewModels in my app. I've explored several different options, but I'm not a huge fan of them really. The most promising I've encountered so far is simply passing messages between the ViewModels, but this is somewhat limiting as the application has the potential to have multiple of the same View open at once, and I need to isolate the parameters to a singular instance of a View/ViewModel.

I'm not currently using the built in `INavigationService` provided by MVVM Light, but I've made one incredibly similar (and if I can solve the parameter injection, I'll likely switch).

Here is a trimmed down version of my navigation service:

```
public class NavigationService : INavigationService
{
    /* this implementation will not allow us to have the same window open
       more than once. However, for this application, that should be sufficient.
    */
    public NavigationService()
    {
        _openPages = new Dictionary<string, Window>();
    }

    private readonly Dictionary<string, Window> _openPages;
    public void ClosePage(string pageKey)
    {
        if (!_openPages.ContainsKey(pageKey)) return;

        var window = _openPages[pageKey];

        window.Close();
        _openPages.Remove(pageKey);
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> OpenPages => _openPages.Keys;

    public void NavigateTo(string pageKey)
    {
        if (!AllPages.ContainsKey(pageKey))
            throw new InvalidPageException(pageKey);

        // Don't re-open a window that's already open
        if (_openPages.ContainsKey(pageKey))
        {
            _openPages[pageKey].Activate();
            return;
        }

        var page = (Window) Activator.CreateInstance(AllPages[pageKey]);
        page.Show();
        page.Closed += OnWindowClosedHandler;
        _openPages.Add(pageKey, page);
    }

    // Probably a better way to remove this.
    private void OnWindowClosedHandler(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        foreach (var item in _openPages.Where(kvp => kvp.Value == sender).ToList())
        {
            _openPages.Remove(item.Key);
        }
    }

    // Reflection might work for this.
    // Might also consider making this more dynamic so it isn't hard-coded into my service
    private readonly Dictionary<string, Type> AllPages = new Dictionary<string, Type>
    {
        ["AddPatientView"] = typeof(AddPatientView),
        ["CheckInView"] = typeof(CheckInView),
        ["MainView"] = typeof(MainWindow),
        ["PatientLookupView"] = typeof(PatientLookupView),
        ["PatientDetailsView"] = typeof(PatientDetailsView)
    };
}
```

Most of my ViewModels use dependency injection to wire-up other injected services, like so:

```
public class CheckInViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public CheckInViewModel(ILicenseValidationService licenseValidationService,
        IPatientFetchService patientFetchService,
        IPatientCheckInService patientCheckInService)
    {
        if (IsInDesignMode)
        {
            Title = "Find Member (Design)";
        }
        else
        {
            Title = "Find Member";

            CanFetch = true;
            FindMemberCommand = new RelayCommand(async () => await FindMemberHandler(), () => CanFetch);
            CheckInPatientCommand = new RelayCommand<Window>(async (window) => await CheckInPatientHandler(window),
                (window) => Patient?.PatientId != null);

            _licenseValidationService = licenseValidationService;
            _patientFetchService = patientFetchService;
            _patientCheckInService = patientCheckInService;
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to implement some method of injecting other parameters alongside my injected services. Has anything like this been done in a relatively straightforward way?

Comment: Have you considered using di to provide the parameters? They seem to be dependencies. Fwiw i prefer single window apps. With multi window the user can all too easily "lose" one or two.

Comment: @Andy DI was an option, but I wasn't sure how to dynamically inject my parameters into the constructor without defining some sort of static service out there.

Answer (score 0):

The way dependency injection works in almost all cases is when you resolve or getinstance a type that then will use the constructor with the most parameters in providing you with an object.

If you register a concrete object against an interface ( or just a type ) then later resolve/getinstance a class which uses one of those things in it's ctor then DI provides that instance you registered.

With MVVMLight you have SimpleIoc and SimpleIoc.Default is equivalent to that static service you're thinking about.

There is a catch with simpleioc. It's very simple.

With simpleioc once you getinstance a viewmodel of a given type then that is a singleton. You can force a different instance by passing a unique key but they're all cached. You can getinstance with parameters and maybe that replaces the current object. I'm not sure offhand. A more sophisticated DI container might be advisable.

Other than that.

Since you're using different windows this creates a bit of a complication in that you want to instantiate a window and that will have a datacontext you need to provide somehow with your parameters.

What you could use is viewmodel first.
You get inavigationservice out DI or resources or a static.

You have a DoWindow(Object vm) method.

When you want to navigate you presumably know the parameters for the vm. New up your viewmodel with parameters. New up a window you use for all views. Set it's content to your viewmodel. That is templated out into what you have as windows now. Except you make them usercontrols. Use Datatype="vmtype" to associate view as template with viewmodel. Bind the title of your window to Content.Title and of course add a Title property to a base viewmodel.

ALternatively with a single window app you can have a contentcontrol fills the area yor views will be shown in. Bind the content of that to a currentviewmodel property and you can use viewmodel first navigation within that window.

Comment: When you say "Use DataType=vmtype" where would you put this and what would it do?